# Integration testing in Grails 3.3.11 does not rollback

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 3.3.11 and I have a problem with my integration tests. It happens that the tests are done, everything is fine, but the data is accumulating in the database. I've tried several things, like using the @Rollback annotation, but it's not happening. There is a lot of garbage in the database. Can you help me? What am I doing wrong. I can't stop the test of saving data in the database. I wanted the Rollback to be automatic.

```
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback

@Integration
@grails.transaction.Rollback
class CmbIdControllerSpec extends Specification {
    @Value('${local.server.port}')
    Integer serverPort
    String accessToken
    String baseUrl
    JSONObject documentPropertiesForTesting
    JSONObject documentForTesting
    String partTest
    String userTest
    String typeIdTest
    String documentIdTest
    def sessionFactory
    def controller

    void setup(){
        baseUrl = "http://localhost:${serverPort}/cmbid/api/v1"
        partTest = "partTest"
        accessToken = "Bearer examplefXk"
    }

    void "Saving a new and valid document properties"() {
        given:
            documentPropertiesForTesting = createNewTestDocumentProperties()
            typeIdTest = documentPropertiesForTesting.get("message").toString().substring(20,52)

        expect:
            documentPropertiesForTesting.get("status") == "ok"
            documentPropertiesForTesting.get("message").contains("properly saved!")

    }

@Rollback
def createNewTestDocumentProperties(){
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    def httpPost = setHttpPost(baseUrl + "/parts/${partTest}/metas")

    JSONObject entireBody = new JSONObject()
    entireBody.accumulate("highlights",setHighlightsDP())
    entireBody.accumulate("screens", setScreensDP())
    entireBody.accumulate("photo", "")
    entireBody.accumulate("style", setStyleDP())

    StringEntity jsonBody = new StringEntity(entireBody.toString())
    httpPost.setEntity(jsonBody)

    CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost)
    JSONObject responseBody = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()))

    httpClient.close()

    return responseBody
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uh... why do you have this :

```
@Rollback
def createNewTestDocumentProperties(){
```

The 'spec' should be handling rollbacks for each individual test properly due to your initial annotation declaration of '@grails.transaction.Rollback'. This secondary class most likely needs to be moved out.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Since I don't understand its behavior, this is a trial and error attempt. I removed the second annotation. But, unfortunately, no rollback happens in any case.

Comment: The rollback happens in the test methods; it won't happen in this secondary class you created.